# convert IR image to RGB with python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tkinter, scikit-image

The code below is intended to take an infrared image (B&W) and convert it to RGB. It does so successfully, but with significant noise. I have included a few lines for noise reduction but they don't seem to help. I've included the starting/resulting photos below. Any advice/corrections are welcome and thank you in advance!

```
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
import glob, os
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import cv2

path = askdirectory(title='Select PNG Folder') # shows dialog box and return the path
outpath = askdirectory(title='Select SAVE Folder') 

# wavelength in microns
MWIR = 4.5

R = .642
G = .532
B = .44

vector = [R, G, B]
vectorsum = np.sum(vector)
vector = vector / vectorsum #normalize
vector = vector*255 / MWIR #changing this value changes the outcome significantly so I 
#have been messing with it in the hopes of fixing it but no luck so far.
vector = np.power(vector, 4)

for file in os.listdir(path):
  if file.endswith(".png"):
    imIn = io.imread(os.path.join(path, file))
    imOut = imIn * vector
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imOut,64,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    erode = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations = 1)
    result = cv2.bitwise_or(imOut, erode)
    io.imsave(os.path.join(outpath, file) + '_RGB.png',imOut.astype(np.uint8))
```

[image: starting image]
[image: result image]

Comment: It would help if you provided an input image example and your resulting output image.

Comment: @fmw42 I've updated the post to include starting/resulting images. thank you!

Comment: @fmw42 could you explain further? feel free to propose edits to my code, I am not confident this is the best way to go about it! thank you very much!

Comment: By "converting it to RGB" do you mean applying some sort of colormap? Could you provide some sort of description of what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: @DanMašek I do yes

Answer (score 1):

Your noise looks like completely random values, so I suspect you have an error in your conversion from `float` to `uint8`. But instead of rolling everything for yourself, why don't you just use:

```
  imOut = cv2.cvtColor(imIn,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Comment: I attempted your solution but get the following error: cv2.error: > Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 3

Comment: OK, so your original images are already in 3-channel RGB, just all channels with equal values (= grayscale). In that case, the question would be what kind of colormap you want to apply.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

Your issue is likely that your channel values are exceeding the 8-bit range.

Sorry, I do not understand the relationship between your R,G,B weights and your MWIR. Dividing by MWIR will do nothing if your weights are properly normalized.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('car.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# make color channels
red = gray.copy()
green = gray.copy()
blue = gray.copy()

# set weights
R = .642
G = .532
B = .44

MWIR = 4.5

# get sum of weights and normalize them by the sum
R = R**4
G = G**4
B = B**4
sum = R + G + B
R = R/sum
G = G/sum
B = B/sum
print(R,G,B)

# combine channels with weights
red = (R*red)
green = (G*green)
blue = (B*blue)
result = cv2.merge([red,green,blue])

# scale by ratio of 255/max to increase to fully dynamic range
max=np.amax(result)
result = ((255/max)*result).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("car_colored.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result

[image]

Comment: would you have a source for the weights you set for R, G, B? In other words, how would I find the optimal combination for these weights

Comment: I just used the weights as provided in the question. I do not know how he got them.

Answer (score 0):

If the noise is coming from the sensor itself, like a grainy noise, you'll need to look into denoising algorithms. `scikit-image` and `opencv` provide some denoising algorithms you can try. Maybe take a look at [this](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_denoise.html) and [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d69/tutorial_py_non_local_means.html).

Comment: I've included the starting/resulting image, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned about `matplotlib.cm`, which handles colormaps. I've been using those to artificially color IR images, and made a brief example using the same black & white car image used above. Basically, I create a colormap .csv file locally, then refer to it for RGB weights. You may have to pick and choose which colormap you prefer, but that's up to personal preference.

Input image:

[image: A car in black and white, "bwcar.jpg"]

Python:

```py
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import cm

# Multiple colormap options are available- I've hardcoded viridis for this example.
colormaps = ["viridis", "plasma", "inferno", "magma", "cividis"] 

def CreateColormap():
    if not os.path.exists("viridis_colormap.csv"):
        # Get 256 entries from "viridis" or any other Matplotlib colormap
        colormap = cm.get_cmap("viridis", 256)
        # Make a Numpy array of the 256 RGB values
        # Each line corresponds to an RGB colour for a greyscale level
        np.savetxt("viridis_colormap.csv", (colormap.colors[...,0:3]*255).astype(np.uint8), fmt='%d', delimiter=',')

def RecolorInfraredImageToRGB(ir_image):       
    # Load RGB lookup table from CSV file
    lookup_table = np.loadtxt("viridis_colormap.csv", dtype=np.uint8, delimiter=",")
    # Make output image, same height and width as IR image, but 3-channel RGB
    result = np.zeros((*ir_image.shape, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    # Take entries from RGB LUT according to greyscale values in image
    np.take(lookup_table, ir_image, axis=0, out=result)       
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CreateColormap()
    img = cv2.imread("bwcar.jpg")
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    recolored = RecolorInfraredImageToRGB(gray)
    cv2.imwrite("car_recolored.png", recolored)
    cv2.imshow("Viridis recolor", recolored)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image: A car recolored using matplotlib's Viridis colormap, "car_recolored.png"]